# How to tackle hundreds of FlywayDB migrations in automated tests

Tags: database-migration, flyway

We are using Flyway DB for a long-lived project, which currently has more than 100 migrations.

In our automated tests, we want to reset the DB before running tests, so that we start with a known state in the db AND we test migrations as well.

The problem we encountered is that running more than 100 migrations is too slow. We think running a single script that creates the current schema, instead of evolving it through all the migrations, would be quite faster. And we don't need the ability to go from version n to n+1 (for arbitrary n), as the only production db we have is already up to date.

Is there any way to "replace" the older migrations with one "snapshot" migration capable of taking a db from version 0 to version 100 in just one script? I guess we could just remove all migrations up to the last one (let's say it is number 100) and replace the migration number 100 with a migration that creates the whole db in one script. Any other ideas?

I know we could just keep the db schema in tests and just wipe the data out before running them, but this is difficult due to some of the rows (just a few) are like constants that where inserted during a migration, and just wiping everything out leaves the db in an inconsistent state.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can follow a process like the one describe here to condense your existing migrations: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing.html

Comment: I went through exactly this procedure in order to Flyway manage an existing project. `pg_dumpall` + a few hours of elbow grease and we had a `V1__base.sql` that went from a clean database to something that was ready for integration testing. Before a project even gets built into any internal Maven repository, it's already had all it's migrations run and a massive suite of medium sized tests hammered on to it. Feels good.